# Как настроить Internal ip У сервера

Tags: linux, сеть, centos

Все привет, сервер на CentOS 7.
Ввожу команду **ifconfig -a** и вижу такой результат

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet YY.YY.YY.YYY  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast YY.YY.YY.YYY
        inet6 YY:YY:YY:YYY  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether YY:YY:YY:YYY  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
```

т.к тут eth1 это мой статический ip адрес сервера смотрящего в интернет
lo - localhost

Мне нужен Internal Ip Addess сервера но его тут нет, как я могу его добавить ?

Как на примере :

```
Location: Paris, France
External IP: 51.15.139.201
Internal IP: 10.10.27.1/24
```

Comment: Обратитесь к своему хостеру. Ему нужно просто поправить свой dhcp. А может быть у него правильно настроен NAT/firewall и все работает. Это легко проверить - сделайте запрос в консоли вида  `curl ipinfo.io` и увидите свой внешний айпи. Потом поднимите web сервер и  попробуйте к нему подключится (либо воспользуйтесь netcat)

Comment: @KoVadim а при чём тут внешний ip, если речь про Internal ip?

Comment: вопрос некорректный, так как и `127.0.0.1/8`, и `YY.YY.YY.YY/24`, и `YY:YY:YY:YYY/64` — это всё **внутренние** адреса вашего компьютера.

Comment: @Suvitruf у меня есть подозрение, что человек опечатался. Но подождем автора вопроса.

Comment: Мне нужен именно что Internal IP, вот пример, Location: Paris, France
External IP: 51.15.139.201
Internal IP: 10.10.27.1/24

Comment: добавил пример выше к вопросу

Comment: Вполне может быть, что у Вашего сервера нет такого понятия. И это нормально. А зачем Вам Internal IP?

Comment: Internal IP, это внутренний адрес. Такие адреса обычно бывают, если хост находится за NAT. То есть, имеется ввиду, что External IP это адрес, например, маршрутизатора, а за ним имеется куча внутренних адресов организации (сервиса). Это все исходит от схемы сети. Если у вас есть прямой адрес сервера, то внутреннего по факту у вас нет или можно принять допустимым ответ @alexanderbarakin

Comment: *добавил пример выше к вопросу* — если очень нужно заполнить третью строчку в приведённой таблице, ну, напишите, например, `127.0.0.1`, или `YY.YY.YY.YY`. с технической точки зрения и то и другое абсолютно корректно. // p.s. вероятно, перед вами поставили какую-то задачу, которую вы не озвучиваете. если эта задача — заполнить приведённую таблицу, то варианты я предложил.

Comment: Почитайте на предмет алиасов, вообще это делается одной командой типа: *ip address add dev eth1 10.10.124.5/24*